# Upgrading from 20.04.4 LTS to 22.04.1 LTS fails due to keyring problem

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade

Running `sudo apt upgrade` gives the following errors:

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/ xenial: /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg != /etc/apt/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/ xenial: /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg != /etc/apt/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You have references to Ubuntu 16.04 in your sources file. They need to be removed 16.04 is long gone. This is messing up the system. They normally get removed when you do an upgrade. Edit the /etc/apt/sources.list  file and you should be ok.

Comment: I checked the /etc/apt/sources.list file for non focal entries and couldn't find any. I also checked the /usr/share/keyrings/ directory and couldn't find any signal-desktop-keyring.gpg file there. Any suggestions what else to check?

Comment: I do not know what to say this is from your question "https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/ xenial:" That is 16.04